Question about homomorphism and first isomorphism theorem Let $G=Z_{12}$ and $H=$ $\{0,4,8\}$ prove that $G/H \cong Z_4$

Let $G=Z_{12}$ and $H=$$\{0,4,8\}$ prove that $G/H \cong Z_4$


The answer in the book is as follows:
we'll define $\phi:G \to \Bbb Z_4$ as $\phi(a)=a(mod4)$
this is a homomorphism because $o(\phi(1_{12}))=o(1_4)|(12,4)=4$
also $Ker(\phi)=H$ and $Im(\phi)= \Bbb Z_4$ therefore from the isomorphism theorem we get $G/H \cong \Bbb Z_4$
My question is why $o(\phi(1_{12}))=o(1_4)|(12,4)=4$ means it is homomorphism isn't the definition $\phi(ab)=\phi(a) \phi(b)$
and why the kernel and image given means $G/H \cong \Bbb Z_4$
Thanks for any help and tips!

Minor point: it's homomorphism, not homeomorphism. I'm not saying that to be pedantic, these words actually mean very different things and appear in different contexts, real confusion could arise.
Anyway, you're right! The definition of homomorphism is $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$ for all $a,b$. However, your author is using an extremely important description of homomorphisms from cyclic groups like $G=\Bbb Z_{12}$. This description is essentially a special case of the quotient principle, which the first isomorphism theorem is also a consequence.

Quotient mapping principle:
If $N\unlhd G$ then $q:G\twoheadrightarrow G/N$ the canonical quotient map has the following property: for all groups $H$, homomorphisms $\psi:G\to H$ with $N\le\ker\psi$ uniquely factor as $\psi=\phi\circ q$ for a homomorphism $\phi:G/N\to H$.

The importance of this is enormous; really, it is "the" real thing we care about with quotients, and generalises to many algebraic contexts. Anyway, let's use this to figure out what it takes to get a homomorphism $\Bbb Z_{12}=\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z\to A$, $A$ some group (in your case, $A=\Bbb Z_4$). By the above principle, that's the same thing as a homomorphism $\psi:\Bbb Z\to A$ with $12\Bbb Z\le\ker\psi$. If $a:=\psi(1)$, then $\psi(n)=a^n$ for all $n$ (and any choice of $a$ would make such a homomorphism) and $12\Bbb Z\le\ker\psi$ really means: $a^{12}=1$. So! Homomorphisms $\Bbb Z_{12}\to A$ are the same thing as choices of elements $a\in A$ with $o(a)|12$. This is what your author means.
Here, $a:=1_4$ was chosen and indeed $4=o(a)$ divides $12$, so the map $G=\Bbb Z_{12}\to\Bbb Z_4$, $[n\text{ mod }12]\mapsto 1_4^n=[n\text{ mod }4]$ is a homomorphism. More concretely, think that $4|12$ is what we need for this to be well-defined; I could always choose a different element $n$ to represent a given congruence class.
